# Android 4.4 KitKat chromium Error: Not implemented virtual void android_webview::AwAutofillManagerDelegate::UpdateAutofillPopupDataListValues

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, chromium, android-4.4-kitkat

My Android App is developed using Sencha Touch 2.3 Phone-gap 2.6. The app works fine on previous versions of Android. But on Android 4.4 (KitKat), I get the following error:

```
11-19 10:33:27.305: E/chromium(1203): [ERROR:aw_autofill_manager_delegate.cc(144)] Not implemented reached in virtual void android_webview::AwAutofillManagerDelegate::UpdateAutofillPopupDataListValues(const std::vector<std::basic_string<short unsigned int, base::string16_char_traits> >&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<short unsigned int, base::string16_char_traits> >&)
```

This error occurs whenever I type into a searchfiled on one of the senchatouch views. I didn't get this error on any android versions prior to 4.4(Kit-Kat)

How can i fix this error?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Up until KitKat, Android's WebViews were wrappers for the WebKit web engine. Google has decided to switch from WebKit to Chromium for KitKat. [Here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/31/kitkat-feature-spotlight-android-webview-is-now-powered-by-chromium-will-make-crappy-web-wrapper-apps-less-crappy/).

This means that thing are bound to get broken. You've stumbled upon one of these things.
My guess is that Sencha will issue a patch somewhere soon.
Until then, either ignore the error and wait, or switch to using an entry field component which is supported by the Chromium engine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's related to sencha, but rather to phonegap because I'm getting the same error on Android 4.4 and I 'm not using sencha. I'm using phonegap version 3.2 though.

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same issue in an app I work on that doesn't use Sencha or PhoneGap.
We are using a plain-old WebView inside an Activity that presents the user with an OAuth2 login window and I am getting the same error.

> [ERROR:aw_autofill_manager_delegate.cc(144)] Not implemented reached in virtual void android_webview::AwAutofillManagerDelegate::UpdateAutofillPopupDataListValues(const std::vector >&, const std::vector >&)